# SICK laser driver fails to start after initialization and handshake?

Tags: ros, laser, sicklms, sicktoolbox-wrapper, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am getting trying to connect SICK LMS200 to ROS, but get the following error after it finds the port, and the laser info.

```
kris@IanCurtis:~/ros/$ rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms

    *** Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...
    Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyUSB1
        Device opened!
    Attempting to start buffer monitor...
        Buffer monitor started!
    Attempting to set requested baud rate...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
    Failed to set requested baud rate...
    Attempting to detect LMS baud rate...
        Checking 19200bps...
A Timeout Occurred!  2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred!  1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
        Checking 38400bps...
        Detected LMS baud @ 38400bps!
        Operating @ 38400bps
    Attempting to sync driver...
        Driver synchronized!
    *** Init. complete: Sick LMS is online and ready!
    Sick Type: Sick LMS 200-30106
    Scan Angle: 180 (deg)
    Scan Resolution: 0.5 (deg)
    Measuring Mode: 8m/80m; 3 reflector bits
    Measuring Units: Centimeters (cm)

[ INFO] [1307303753.596993806]: Setting variant to (180, 0.500000)
    Requesting partial scan data stream...
        Data stream started!
[ERROR] [1307303753.973765819]: woah! error!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'SickToolbox::SickThreadException'
Aborted
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10166/sick-laser-driver-fails-to-start-after-initialization-and-handshake?/) by [Kristiyan Georgiev](https://answers.ros.org/users/531/kristiyan-georgiev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-06-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-06**:
It seems odd, that the driver says it found the sick at 38.4k. I don't know this driver, but maybe you have to configure the serial port manually by `setserial /dev/ttyUSB0 baud_base 500000 uart 16654`. I don't know if that works for USB or helps at all.

**Comment by [Kristiyan Georgiev](https://answers.ros.org/users/531/kristiyan-georgiev/) on 2011-06-06**:
Yes, I have it working with a custom Java drivers @ 500K in 180 deg, with 1 deg resolution

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-06**:
Do you know if the scanner if working hardware-wise. Have you run another driver that works?

**Comment by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on 2012-06-08**:
Did you figure it out? I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0